# using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery for stored proc which do not return data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I need to do stored procedure call which do not return any data, I have tried using NamedStoredProcedureQuery but it fails saying

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : send_message*

**SendMessage.java**

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "send_message",
        procedureName = "send_message",
        resultClasses = {SendMessage.class},
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Date.class, name = "date"),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "message")
        }
)
public class SendMessage implements Serializable {
}
```

**MessageDao.java**

```
@Component
public class MessageDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;



    public void sendMessage(SendRequest sendRequest){
        StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("send_message")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(0 , Date.class , ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1 , String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.setParameter(0, sendRequest.getBusinessDate());
        query.setParameter(1, sendRequest.getMessage());
   
        query.execute();
    }
```

Getting below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : send_message
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(SessionImpl.java:3586) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Is there any way I can make this work, I cant put @Entity in SendMessage.java as it is not associated with any db table, Also do not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` only works when you put it on an Entity.

Don't you have an entity where you can put it?

Alternatively you could create a `orm.xml` file in `src/resources/META-INF` and put it there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://www.datanucleus.org/xsd/jpa/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datanucleus.org/xsd/jpa/orm
        http://www.datanucleus.org/xsd/jpa/orm_2_2.xsd" version="2.2">

    <named-stored-procedure-query name="send_message" result-class="SendMessage" 
        procedure-name="send_message">

        <parameter direction="IN" name="date" type="Date"/>
        <parameter direction="IN" name="message" type="String"/>

    </named-stored-procedure-query>    
</entity-mappings>
```